# Why is a variable name followed by an underscore not evaluated correctly during string interpolation in Perl?

Tags: perl, double-quotes, string-interpolation

Why is a variable name followed by an underscore not evaluated correctly during string interpolation in Perl?

```
my $i = 3;

print "i = $i\n"; # works, prints "i = 3"
print "_i = _$i\n"; # works, prints "_i = _3"
print "i_ = $i_\n"; # FAILS, prints "i_ = "
print "_i_ = _$i_\n"; # sort of works, prints "_i_ = _"
```

Comment: [Always use strict and always use warnings!](http://joelslinux.blogspot.com/2011/06/use-strict-and-warnings.html)

Answer (score 26):

In addition to the other answers, you can use the alternative syntax for specifying variables:

```
print "i_ = ${i}_\n";
```

Note the usage of curly brackets: `{` and `}` to specify the variable name. Whenever in doubt, you may opt for this syntax.

Answer (score 18):

`$i_` is a valid identifier, so it's trying to print the value of that variable (which you haven't set, so it is `undef`).

Turn on `strict` and `warnings`.

Comment: I noticed your buddhabrot, Mat. Perhaps this would interest you: https://github.com/buddhabrot/buddhabrot  (I couldn't reach you any other way so I had to find an innocent comment somewhere).

Answer (score 7):

Mat is right. If you really need that underscore immediately after the value use backslash: `"$i\_"`.

Comment: `print 'i_ = ' . $i . "_\n";`

Comment: I much prefer `${i}` over the backslash, since they do different things in other contexts.

Comment: A backslash suppressed interpolation.  Curlies around a variable name interpolate the value of that variable.  `print "${i}_\n"` is easier on my eyes and brain, because those two things would do the same thing if unquoted.

Answer (score 3):

Always use these:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```